# Отправка сообщения в беседу Вконтакте от имени группы в определённые дни и время

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

столкнулся с проблемой - не могу найти, как можно реализовать отправку сообщений в определённое время в беседу, кажется, что перерыл весь гугл, но ничего нужного не нашёл, если вы, читающий это разбираетесь в данной области, будьте добры дать подсказку новичку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть возможность держать свой код работающим 24/7, то реализовать это можно через модуль [shedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/). Пример кода:

```py
import vk_api
import schedule

token = 'токен'


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def send_m():
    vk.messages.send(chat_id=chat_id, message="привет!", random_id=get_random_id())

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(send_m)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Второй вариант - можно воспользоваться хостингом, который будет держать код постоянно включённым. Например [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), который позволяет реализовать подобное бесплатно - [здесь](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python) описано как

Третий вариант - развернуть веб приложение на flask. Можно создать задачу на [Cron job](https://cron-job.org/), которая будет посылать запрос на приложение в указанное время (тем самым запуская его). Для этого также бота нужно будет развернуть на каком либо хостинге (том же heroku). Пример кода:

```py
import vk_api
import schedule
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello. I am alive!"

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()

token = 'токен'

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

vk.messages.send(chat_id=chat_id, message="привет!", random_id=get_random_id())

keep_alive()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо